# Do superconducting materials have "zero" work function?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrical-resistance, superconductivity

I understand that superconductors have zero resistivity, however, I wonder if there is a relation between resistivity and the work function of a specific material so that a superconductor has zero (or a low value) work function. If so, photons with very long wavelengths can release electrons from the surface of a superconductor. Am I right?

Answer (score 8):

The work function is a measure of how much energy it takes to completely remove an electron from a material and send it into **free space**, and costs on the order of 1000-5000 meV of energy. The resistance is a measure of how much energy is needed to move electrons infinitesimally ($\Delta E\sim0$) **within the material** where any individual electron will only receive an energy many, many orders of magnitude lower than the work function, unless you drive with very high currents/voltages.

In superconductors, the resistance is zero until you excite electrons at energies on the order of a few meV (thousands of times smaller than the work function). **So no, superconductors do indeed have a non-zero work function**. In fact, if *any* material had a zero work function, they would be inherently unstable because electrons would constantly leave and escape into free space.

However, your question is still a good one. The energy cost for jumping from one superconductor to another can be negligibly small and fully coherent. This type of effect lays at the heart of [Josephson junctions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephson_effect) and [tunneling of electrons between two superconductors](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconducting_tunnel_junction)